# Check if value is the only thing in an array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => red
    [2] => red
)
```

I am trying to check if **red** is the only thing in the array, I would want it to fail if the array looked like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => yellow
    [2] => red
)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried to achieve this requirement?

Comment: What if there's more than one 'red' in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `array_unique()` you can just count the number of occurances returned. If its > 1 you have not got all red

```
<?php
$array = ['red','red','red'];

if ( count(array_unique($array)) == 1 && array_unique($array)[0] == 'red' ) {
    echo 'all red';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: So many different ways to achieve this it seems! I went with your array_unique option as it seems most readable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$array = [
    'foo',
    'foo',
    'foo'
];

$values = array_count_values($array);
$count = count($array);

if (!empty($values['foo']) && $count === $values['foo']) {
    echo 'all array values match foo';
} else {
    echo 'foo not found in array';
}
```

here we count values in the array vs the overall count of the array

**Edit**: *The only problem is, you have to know the value you're comparing against to get the result*

**Edit 2**: Addressing issue raised by MickMackusa:

> *and the other problem is, if the value that you are looking for doesn't exist at all in the input array, then it won't exist as a key in the $values array and thus your code will generate a Notice. ...not good.*

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of `count()` and `array_filter()` to find count of unwanted item in array.

```
$invalidItems = count(array_filter($arr, function($item){
    return $item != 'red';
}));

if ($invalidItems)
    echo 'invalid';
else    
    echo 'valid';
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/XrAVX)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `array_unique()` to get it to remove duplicates and then count the size of the remaining list, you can also then check that the 1 value is whatever value your expecting...

```
$unique = array_unique($a);
if ( count($unique) == 1 && $unique[0] == 'value' ) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need more than one function call to check for non-red values exist.  The following checks if there are any non-red elements.

Codes ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IbOHr))

```
$array = ['red','red','red'];
var_export(!array_diff($array, ['red']));  // true
echo "\n";
var_export(!array_filter($array, function($v){return $v !== 'red';}));  // true

$array = ['red','yellow','red'];
var_export(!array_diff($array, ['red']));  // false
echo "\n";
var_export(!array_filter($array, function($v){return $v !== 'red';}));  // false
```

I think `array_filter()` is a more "direct" technique, but `array_diff()` doesn't need a custom function so it is arguably easier to read.

If your coding logic must require the existence of `red` as well as disqualify arrays that contain a non-red element, then just add a condition that checks if the array has any elements.  ([more precise demo](https://3v4l.org/eA2Qe))

---

And for best performance, use a loop with a break -- this way you don't have to iterate the entire array unless absolutely necessary.  Early `break`s are a good thing.  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/cLd6H)

```
$array = ['red','yellow','red'];
$result = true;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value != 'red') {
        $result = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `red` is there, then remove duplicate values and check that there is only one:

```
if(in_array('red', $array) && (count(array_unique($array)) == 1)) {
    // yes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school foreach (all) red or dead:

```
<?php
$things = ['red', 'white', 'blue'];
foreach($things as $colour)
    if ($colour !== 'red')
        throw new Exception('dead');
```